# Evaluating UITraitCollection's hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo:) result

Tags: ios, swift, uitraitcollection, ios-darkmode

In my app I need to make some custom UI changes when iOS system dark mode settings change. According to https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/ it's explicitly mentioned to implement `traitCollectionDidChange` and compare the previous and current trait collection using `hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo:)`.

Documentation says:

> Use this method to determine whether changing the traits of the current environment would also change the colors in your interface. For example, changing the userInterfaceStyle or accessibilityContrast property usually changes the colors of your interface.

In my view controller's subclass I implemented

```swift
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *),
            self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {

            let isSameUserInterfaceStyle = (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle)
            let isSameAcessibilityContrast = (self.traitCollection.accessibilityContrast == previousTraitCollection?.accessibilityContrast)

            // do custom stuff
        }
    }
```

But in some cases both `isSameUserInterfaceStyle` and `isSameAcessibilityContrast` evaluate to `true` which I did not expect if `hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo:)` also returns `true`.
I'm not a fan of working around Apple's suggested API usage but on the other hand I don't want to make unnecessary changes to my UI if `userInterfaceStyle` did not actually change. So I'm not sure if I should rely on the result of `hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo:)` or if it suffices to just compare `userInterfaceStyle` of both trait collections.

Comment: Could you please print both trait collections when this happens? Maybe something else is going on...

Comment: @RTasche You should post that as a full answer below. That's an interesting bit of information.

Answer (score 1):

A deeper investigation of both trait collections brought to light that the current trait collection's `userInterfaceLevel` property was set `.elevated`. All other properties were identical. The change in `userInterfaceLevel`'s value was caused by presenting another view controller as a popover. Considering this fact I need to additionally check for `self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle` to determine whether the dark / light appearance has actually changed.